# How to change header font size of IEEEtran document class?

Tags: header-footer, fontsize, ieeetran

Currently, I am working on my research paper using IEEEtran document class. My institution provides a paper template in Word version. It uses IEEEtran document style but with some modifications. One of those is the header font size. The header font size should be on 10pt. The default of IEEEtran document class has a smaller size than my institution provided paper template. So, my question, how to change header font size of IEEEtran document class?

Thank you.

note: the header contains journal name, volume, and also page number.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper template? The headers/footers may be affected by the class option(s).

Comment: I am late to tell you that the paper template provided by my institution is actually in Word version.

Answer (score 1):

Class `IEEEtran` defines and uses macros `\@IEEEheaderstyle` and `\@IEEEfooterstyle` for the font setup of headers and footers. The definitions depend on the option settings, from `IEEEtran.cls`:

```
% set up the running headers and footers
%
% header and footer font and size specifications
\def\@IEEEheaderstyle{\normalfont\scriptsize}
\def\@IEEEfooterstyle{\normalfont\scriptsize}
%
% compsoc uses sans-serif headers and footers
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \def\@IEEEheaderstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize}
  \def\@IEEEfooterstyle{\normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize}
\fi
```

The macros can be redefined to use a larger font than `\scriptsize`, e.g.:

```
\def\@IEEEheaderstyle{\normalfont\small}
\def\@IEEEfooterstyle{\normalfont\small}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, it doesn't work. I run only the redefined of header style using both `\small` and `\large`. The header font remains the same.

Comment: The problem is in the modifications, to which we have no access.  My suggestion is to find the source code and search for things like "header" or "\normalsize".

Comment: I have same thought, @JohnKormylo. Anyway, I can change the header font size by adding font size command into `\markboth` command. `\markboth` is a place where you put your journal name, volume, number, and etc. But, the result look likes ugly because the header and page number font size are not same.